# Dynamic import being added to webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, dynamic-import

I want to import a module under a certain condition, so I'm doing it through dynamic import syntax:

```
  if (showModal) {
    import('fancy-modal').then(({ initModal }) => {
      initModal();
    });
  }
```

This works but it adds the "fancy-modal" library code to the webpack bundle no matter what the value of `showModal` is.

I thought dynamic imports would only load the library if the condition is true, why is it being loaded by webpack no matter what?

Comment: Are you saying that it's built into the same javascript bundle when you run `webpack` in production, rather than splitting in into its own chunk?

Comment: If you are statically `import`'ing that same module somewhere else in your codebase it will be put into the entry chunk. Just FYI. I'm not quite sure what your problem is based on how you worded it.

Comment: I understand but I’m not importing it anywhere else in my code base. My issue is, I expect it not to be added to the bundle if the condition is false yet it is. I expect it to be included only if the condition is true at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack will always build all of your code, unless the variable is guaranteed to always be `false`, e.g. when using a `define` plugin and using `if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){ // do some dev only stuff}`.

By default webpack 4 will split out dynamic imports into chunks using the split chunks plugin https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/

If you have imported `fancy-modal` anywhere else in your code in a "non dynamic" way, webpack will realise this and just build it once all in the same bundle, so you won't get any benefit from the dynamic import.

Comment: I need this modal only on dev, thats why I don't want the module to appear in the production bundle. `showModal` is coming from a config file, its always set to false on prod.  I can't use `process.env.NODE_ENV` because the modal is executed at run time not build time.

Comment: If it's executed at runtime then it will always be in the build output, however it should be in it's own chunk and not in the main bundle. So at runtime it shouldn't load the js at all. Is the issue that it is still loading the chunk, or do you only get one output js file?

Comment: Yea the issue is it’s part of the output file. Do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: Are you running your build in production mode (NODE_ENV=production)? How many js files are output from the build? Have you defined your own webpack config, or are you using something like create-react-app?