# Vue - Remove specific JavaScript files for production mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, dev-to-production, webpack-production

I have lots of `.js` files to import in Vue components in my project. Some of these JavaScript files are meant to be used in development mode and they won't be included in production but I am not allowed to delete these files in project. For example;

There are two JavaScript files called `authDev.js` and `authProd.js`. Their usage is basically the same but their content are different from each other. Inside of these JavaScript files there are functions and I export them to be able to import in several Vue components.

The first question, If I dynamically export or import them, will webpack include these files when I run `npm run build`? In other words, let's say I created a JavaScript file but I didn't export it, so I didn't import it to anywhere either. Does webpack understand that this JavaScript file is not used in anywhere of these Vue project and discard it when it builds my project to production? Or does it include every single file that existed in the project?

The second question, is there a way to tell the webpack that those JavaScript files will not be included in dist folder these will... I mean, can I specify files for development and production?

First I thought I could import or export them based on a condition but when I try to put my imports in `if statements`, it gives me an error and says `"imports must be at the top level"`. So I tried to export them dynamically but couldn't do it either.

Then I try to remove specific blocks of codes in files. There are packages and plugins to remove every console outputs from Vue projects but I couldn't find anything to remove or discard specific lines of codes.

At last, I decided to took a way to include and exclude specific files. Is there a way to do it? If it is, how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

**THE SOLUTION (EDITED)**

For a quick test, I created two `.js` files called `auth-development.js` and `auth-production.js` in `src/assets/js/filename.js` location. Here are the contents of them;

```
auth-production.js

export const auth = {
    authLink: "http://production.authlink/something/v1/",
    authText: "Production Mode"
}

auth-development.js

export const auth = {
    authLink: "http://localhost:8080/something/v1/",
    authText: "Development Mode"
}
```

Then I modified my webpack config which is in the `vue.config.js` file;

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
              'conditionalAuth': path.resolve(__dirname, `src/assets/js/auth-${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`)
            }
          }
    }
  }
```

Vue was giving `"path is undefined"` error, I added the top part of the code to handle that error. I used `process.env.NODE_ENV` to get the words `development` and `production` to add the end of my javascript files so that I can define their path.

Then I dynamically imported this `conditionalAuth` to a test component called `"HelloWorld"` as follows;

```
<script>
import * as auth from 'conditionalAuth';

export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data(){
    return {
      auth: auth
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And I used them like this;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>You are in the {{ auth.auth.authText}}</p>
    <p>{{ auth.auth.authLink }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

In this way when I `npm run serve` it imports `auth-development.js` but if I `npm run build` and try the `index.html` in the `dist` folder on a live server, it only imports the `auth-production.js`.

At last, when I check the final build, `auth-development.js` is not built for my dist version of the project. It only imports the production javascript file in the chunk.

Comment: you can use require instead of import to use a conditional or dynamic import. it will not include in bundle if the condition is always false

Comment: Can you given an example or is there a document that I can read?

Comment: see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083969/dynamic-import-being-added-to-webpack-bundle

Comment: What I want to learn is, in this answer, the import is based on a condition, if this condition isn't met, the component is not imported at all. In this scenario, will webpack still build this component for production or will it discard it?

Comment: It depends on a condition. This is specific not to Webpack but to a setup, which isn't shown. Is or Vue CLI or?

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV` Aren't you concerned about accidentally setting the variable wrong, or do you have another mechanism which makes this a non-issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the file names are: `auth-development.js` and `auth-production.js`, you can use webpack `alias` to import file according to environment.

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
      'conditionalAuth': path.resolve(__dirname, `path/to/js/auth-${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`)
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json']
  }
```

then you should be able to import the desired file like:

```
import * as auth from 'conditionalAuth';
```

Comment: It seems logic. I'll try and let you know. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I used this way of importing .js files. I also tried with the .json format and it works. But the same logic is not working with Vue components.  I tried to create a new alia in the vue.config with the same way comp-${process.env.NODE_ENV}.vue but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I updated my answer, added the `extensions` property to the resolve object. See if it helps.

Comment: I added the extensions property and just to make an example I added the following; conditionalComponent: path.resolve(__dirname, `src/components/component-${process.env.NODE_ENV}.vue`). Created two vue components and import them just like in your answer import * as myComp from "conditionalComponent" and I put the myComponent in components : {}. When I use the myComponent the Vue is looking for conditionalComponent but it's not looking for component-development.vue or component-production.vue (Names of my sample vue components)